# IIS Rewrite 2 Angular applications

Tags: angular, iis, url-rewriting, virtual-directory

I have 2 Angular applications. One in my main domain and the other one in a virtual directory called "merchant", inside this domain.
I want to have rewrite rules for both so that I can enter the URL in the address bar without having 404 page. For this I put a web.config in both folders, but I am not able to get both applications rewrite rules working at the same time.

In the main application web.config I have

```
<rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="block" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="^merchant/(.*)$" />
            <action type="Redirect" url="merchant/{R:1}" />
          </rule>
       <rule name="Application Routes" patternSyntax="Wildcard">
          <match url="*" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />

          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

With this conf, the rewriting works well for the main application, but not for the second. I thought the first rule would redirect to the virtual folder web.config but seems it's not. Below the rules in my virtual folder web.config:

```
<rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="AngularJS Routes" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url=".*" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="/merchant/" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

Of course if I remove all the rules from the main web.config, the second is working, but not the first anymore...

How can I get both at the same time?

Comment: Afaik you can only have one web.config per site, so combine the rules to one file.

Comment: It's 2 different IIS applications, just the folder of the second one is inside the main folder

Comment: Then that's the problem. Should be one site. :)

Comment: Ie. it could probably be done with a reverse proxy but way easier to just have one site. If that's not an option google reverse proxy...

Comment: One site with 2 separate angular applications, I don't know if that's possible. Anyway I finally found a solution, I'll reply in few minutes

Comment: Oops, double post deleted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found a solution. As commented by funkizer I had to put all rules in the same web.config
Below the main web.config with 2 rules

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
   <rule name="AngularJS Routes" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^merchant/(.*)$" />
      <conditions >
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="merchant/" />
    </rule>
   <rule name="Application Routes" patternSyntax="Wildcard">
      <match url="*" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />

      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

I also had to keep the other web.config but I removed all rules inside.
Now both applications can be accessed with direct url